# C open file multiple times

Tags: c, fopen

I have a file opened with `fopen`. There is a way to reopen the same file (while it is opened) but have a **different** seek? (so i can use fread independently)

Comment: Yes, but why didn't you just try it? (Might actually be OS dependent.)

Comment: If you want multiple offsets within the file to read, `mmap()` may be an option too, depending on your OS. Then you can just index into the file using memory addresses.

Comment: @GeorgSchölly that is often a very bad recommendation in languages with undefined/unspecified/implementation defined behaviour.

Comment: @BoBTFish: You're right. Didn't think of that at all. Thanks for the helpful hint. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

there is no problem if you keep reading only.

Be careful if you write in the file especially if you have 2 threads that access with read/write to the file at the same time

If your code looks like that

```
FILE *fp1, *fp2;

fp1 = fopen("file", "r");
fp2 = fopen("file", "r");
```

then you have 2 seeks in the same file. and the position of seeks are independent. reading from `fp1` does not have any impact in `fp2`

Comment: @polslinux the other option (and probably more stable one) is to create a structure that maintains each seek point, and use a function to read from either head.

Comment: so there is no problem. you can open the file many times and have many seeks at the same time

Comment: open the file with a new file descriptor otherwise you will loose the seek of the last file descriptor

Comment: Careful, it is implementation-defined, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50114472/9305398