# Does fopen return NULL pointer if file is already open?

Tags: c, file-handling, mingw32

I was assuming that `fopen` returns `NULL` pointer if file is already open. But it looks `fopen` does not return `NULL` in case file is already open in `"w"` mode. Below is the code that I used to try this and I do not get any errors. I tried with mingw32 as well as TDM-GCC-64 compilers. If I am not mistaken, C++ gives error if file is already open.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp1, *fp2;
    
    fp1 = fopen("file1.txt", "w");
    fp2 = fopen("file1.txt", "w");
    
    if(fp2 == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error in opening file\n");
        return(0);
    }
    
    // Edit: added following code to check the behavior if write operation
    // is performed simultaneously
    
    fputc('A', fp1);
    fputc('M', fp1);
    fputc('S', fp1);
    fputc('B', fp2);
    
    fclose(fp1);
    fclose(fp2);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Edit: Added extra code to write some data to both `fp1` and `fp2` and see the behavior. If executed, `file1.txt` contains data `BMS` and seems to be correct behavior and `fp1` and `fp2` move independently as expected. First `AMS` is written using `fp1` and then `A` is replaced by `B` using `fp2` and final output is `BMS`.

Comment: So what happens in the posted code?

Comment: @Rajesh It's about file sharing, on Windows if your lib implementation calls `_fsopen` with `SH_DENYNO` (for example) then another program (or the same one...) can open the file multiple times (also for writing). What will happen depends both on the implementation and the underlying OS (concurrent writes are not that easy, at least on Windows). Note however that default `fopen()` assumes sharing because usually *nix OSes uses other synchronization primitives (see `fcntl()`)

Comment: Cit: On most library implementations, the `errno` variable is also set to a system-specific error code on failure

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the C Standard (7.19.3.8), it is implementation-defined:

> Functions that open additional (nontemporary) files require a file name, which is a string. The rules for composing valid file names are implementation-defined. Whether the same file can be simultaneously open multiple times is also implementation-defined.

On top of that, it is discouraged for other reasons, see for instance [SEI CERT C Coding Standard's FIO24-C recommendation](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/FIO24-C.+Do+not+open+a+file+that+is+already+open):

> Some implementations do not allow multiple copies of the same file to be open at the same time. Consequently, portable code cannot depend on what will happen if this rule is violated. Even on implementations that do not outright fail to open an already-opened file, a TOCTOU (time-of-check, time-of-use) race condition exists in which the second open could operate on a different file from the first due to the file being moved or deleted (see FIO45-C. Avoid TOCTOU race conditions while accessing files for more details on TOCTOU race conditions).

Comment: I added extra code and edited the post. If we try to write simultaneously using both file pointers, both are getting written and file pointers are independently handled and I guess this is correct behavior.